# What is the function of add_custom_target in CMake?

Tags: cmake

From the ***CMake Cookbook***, I see that we can use the command `add_custom_command` and `add_custom_target` to run a custom command at build time. There is a toy example that I want to extract compressed files in subdirectory and link it to the final executable files. We have two `CMakeLists.txt` files and the following one is in the subdirectory.

```
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
find_package(LAPACK REQUIRED)

set(MATH_SRCS
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/wrap_BLAS_LAPACK/CxxBLAS.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/wrap_BLAS_LAPACK/CxxLAPACK.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/wrap_BLAS_LAPACK/CxxBLAS.hpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/wrap_BLAS_LAPACK/CxxLAPACK.hpp
  )

add_custom_target(BLAS_LAPACK_wrappers
  WORKING_DIRECTORY
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  DEPENDS
    ${MATH_SRCS}
  COMMENT
    "Intermediate BLAS_LAPACK_wrappers target"
  VERBATIM
  )

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT
    ${MATH_SRCS}
  COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar xzf ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/wrap_BLAS_LAPACK.tar.gz
  WORKING_DIRECTORY
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  DEPENDS
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/wrap_BLAS_LAPACK.tar.gz
  COMMENT
    "Unpacking C++ wrappers for BLAS/LAPACK"
  )

add_library(math "")

target_sources(math
  PRIVATE
    ${MATH_SRCS}
  )

target_include_directories(math
  INTERFACE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/wrap_BLAS_LAPACK
  )

# BLAS_LIBRARIES are included in LAPACK_LIBRARIES
target_link_libraries(math
  PUBLIC
    ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES}
  )
```

The following `CMakeLists.txt` is in the main directory.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5 FATAL_ERROR)

# Fortran needed to discover LAPACK with some compilers
project(recipe-04 LANGUAGES CXX Fortran)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_subdirectory(deps)

add_executable(linear-algebra linear-algebra.cpp)

target_link_libraries(linear-algebra
  PRIVATE
    math
  )
```

I do not know why we need the `add_custom_target` in this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `add_custom_command` cannot be executed without generating any target. That is why we need the custom target to run this command. What's more, it can only execute at the configure time. If we want to run the command after we configure the `CMakeLists.txt` file, we can create a custom target to achieve that as the following.

```
add_custom_target(BLAS_LAPACK_wrappers
  WORKING_DIRECTORY
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  DEPENDS
    ${MATH_SRCS}
  COMMENT
    "Intermediate BLAS_LAPACK_wrappers target"
  VERBATIM
  )

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT
    ${MATH_SRCS}
  COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar xzf ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/wrap_BLAS_LAPACK.tar.gz
  WORKING_DIRECTORY
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  DEPENDS
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/wrap_BLAS_LAPACK.tar.gz
  COMMENT
    "Unpacking C++ wrappers for BLAS/LAPACK"
  )
```

After we configure the `CMakeLists.txt` file, we use the `Cmake --build . --target=BLAS_LAPACK_wrappers` the execute it at the build time.